# What is read.data in R? Why can't I find it in any docs?

Tags: r

I'm trying to debug my first R script and I came across this line:

```
data <- read.data(dir, indiv, label)
```

I've been googling "R read.data" for the past 30 minutes and absolutely nothing is coming up. Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a good way to look up things I see in R scripts that I don't know what they are?

And what is this particular line doing anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a function defined by the author of the script. Search for it in the code you have.

Comment: Ok, you're right.  I found it in another file this one imports.  What threw me off was that I saw read.csv as a built in function, so I thought read was built in.  But then I learned the . doesn't mean anything in R.  I.e., read isn't some package that contains functions but rather the begininging of function names.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to check:

1. Does your script define the function 'read.data' somewhere? `read.data <- function(...`
2. Does your script use `library()` or `require()` to load another package? In that case, the `read.data` function can be defined in that package.
3. Does your script use `source` to read another script? Check that script then...

Answer (score 2):

package `sos` to the rescue:

`read.data` is a deprecated function in the `rjags` package

```
> library(sos)
> findFn("read.data")
```

Finds this result:

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/rjags/html/read.data.html

From this page:

```
Read data for a JAGS model from a file.
Usage

read.jagsdata(file)
read.bugsdata(file)

Note

Earlier versions of the rjags package had a read.data function which read data
in either format, but the function name was ambiguous (There are many data file 
format in R) so this is now deprecated.
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a base function named `read.data`. If you want to find help for an R function (for example `read.table`), simply type `?read.table` at the interactive prompt.

This line calls a read.data function which is either defined in that script or in something else it loads (such as libraries with the `library()` or `require()`, other scripts with `source()`). You'll need to search those sources to find this function.